# Automatic deserialization of String to Object with Jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

## Context

Say you have:

```
public class Dto {
  private String name;
  private String List<Custom> customs;

  // getters and setters...
}
```

and

```
public class Custom {
  private String something;
  private String else;
  
  // getters and setters...
}
```

Your Spring MVC `RestController` receives a list of `Dto`:

```
@PostMapping
public String create(@RequestBody @Valid List<Dto> dtos) {
  return myService.process(features);
}
```

## Input

However, you know that the client-side service which will send data to your controller will send something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "customs": [
      "{\n        \"something\": \"yes\",\n        \"else\": \"no\"\n      }"
    ]
  }
]
```

Notice how **the `List<Custom>` actually ends up being received as a `List<String>`**. Please assume this cannot be changed on the client-side and we have to deal with it on the server-side.

## Question

**Is there a Jackson annotation which would automagically take the input `String` and try to serialize it into a `Custom` class?**

## Attempts

A few things that didn't work, including:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
private List<Custom> customs;
```

along with

```
public Custom(String json) {
  try {
    new ObjectMapper().readerFor(Custom.class).readValue(json);
  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

As it is, we have had to change the `customs` type to `List<String>` and add a utility method which converts a `String` into a `Custom` using an `ObjectMapper`. This is rather dissatisfying.

Comment: That's because in your attempt you used 'JsonSerialize' a this annotation is used for responses. you need to use `JsonDeserialize` with this you can do your custom deserializer and should work

Comment: @Marco Good point. Nonetheless, my question is mostly about obtaining something automatic. I would much rather not have to maintain a custom deserializer when the input ``String`` trivially matches the desired ``Custom`` class.

Comment: Example payload is not a valid `JSON`. I assume, you broke it when you wanted to obscure real one. Am I right?

Comment: @MichałZiober sorry, I forgot to escape the quotes. That's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement custom deserialiser or converter which would be used to convert given payload to required type. One trick, you could use is to create new `ObjectMapper` and use it for internal deserialisation.

Example usage:

```
class CustomConverter extends StdConverter<String, Custom> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Custom convert(String value) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(value, Custom.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(value);
        }
    }
}

class Dto {
    private String name;

    @JsonDeserialize(contentConverter = CustomConverter.class)
    private List<Custom> customs;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Deserializer.

```java
public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Custom> { 
 
    public CustomDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 
 
    public CustomDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc); 
    }
 
    @Override
    public Custom deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        int id = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("id")).numberValue();
        String name = node.get("name").asText();
        ...
        return new Custom(id, name, ...);
    }
}
```

and register the deserializer on the `Custom` class:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
public class Custom {
  ...
}
```

Comment: But this isn't an automatic process. Is there not a ``Deserializer`` which takes care of analyzing an input ``String`` as a Json with extra blanks (``spaces`` and ``enters`` in between the properties declarations) designating a specific class?

Comment: Jackson requires annotations or deserializers/serializers. On the other hand [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is much more flexible.